# Pass an id from a template to a view in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, django-views

I´m having some problems with this. I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="button" name="_mail" value="Enviar Mail" id="buttonId"> 
</form>
```

it´s just a buttom. Then in my views i have this code:

```
def verFactura(request, id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk = id_factura)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(factura = fact)
    template = 'verfacturas.html'
    iva = fact.importe_sin_iva * 0.21
    total = fact.importe_sin_iva + iva

    extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['fact'] = fact
    extra_context['cliente'] = cliente
    extra_context['iva'] = iva
    extra_context['total'] = total


    if "_mail" in request.POST: 
        send_templated_mail(template_name='receipt',
                    from_email='imiguel@exisoft.com.ar',
                    recipient_list =['ignacio.miguel.a@gmail.com'],
                    context=extra_context)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('../facturas')
    else:(if i don´t write this else i get an error)
        return render(request,template, extra_context)

return render(request,template, extra_context)
```

And a member of SO suggested to use javascript to handle the click event like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#buttonId').click(function(){
        alert("Email enviado");
  });
});
```

i know nothing about javascript but i was hoping that with only this i could call the IF statement in the view. But obviously this part of the code never gets call and i don´t recieve any email.

So, can anyone tell me where is my mistake? i have a feeling that the part of the If statement is wrong but i don´t why

I would really appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: Could you check what is the value of `request.POST.get('_mail')`?

Comment: yes, actually is not loading the template it shows this error: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable. All i want to do is to send the email only if the user press the buttom.

Comment: Exception Type: TypeError at /Exi/verFactura/1
Exception Value: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if "buttonId" in request.POST.get('click', False):

There's no "click" parameter. With this instruction you try to iterate ("in") through the False value.

Try:

```
if '_mail' in request.POST:
```

Comment: thanks. The error doesn´t appeare anymore, but the email is not sent. Do you see any other error in the code?

Comment: I dont see any, its impossible to tell from here. Is it falling into the `if` condition? Are you using a smtp.EmailBackend in your settings? Do your email server is properly configured? If you change to console backend, do you see any output?

Comment: If i don´t put the IF statement and i enter to this url, the email is sent and i receive it without any problem. But i don´t want to do that, that´s why y put a buttom at the bottom of the page and if the user clicks the email is sent

Comment: Change the input type `<input type="submit" ...`  (this will send the POST request). Also, maybe you want to wrap the POST processing with `if request.method == "POST":`